# How to extend React functional component on hooks?

Tags: reactjs, class, user-interface, inheritance, react-hooks

I know that it's not recommended approach but anyway I curious about how it could be done via functional components and hooks. Considering the following example:

```
class SimpleComponent extends Component {
    method1 = () => {
        console.log('Method 1');
    };

    method2 = () => {
        console.log('Method 2');
    };

    renderMessage2() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.method2}>Message 2</div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div onClick={this.method1}>Message 1</div>
                {this.renderMessage2()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class EnhancedComponent extends SimpleComponent {
    method1 = () => {
        console.log('Enhanced Method 1');
    };

    method2 = () => {
        console.log('Enhanced Method 2');
    };

    renderMessage2() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.method2}>Enhanced Message 2</div>
        );
    }
}
```

How can we achieve such behavior with functional components and hooks?

Comment: So you asked a question about doing something that *isn't recommended* and **answered yourself** with an approach that *you don't like*? I don't understand what purpose this serves.

Comment: Inheritance is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @BrianThompson I just want to understand maybe there is another, more elegant, way to do it.

Comment: @JMadelaine and what can we do if we want to provide a possibility to customize our components? Props components look messy especially if we don't know what could be overwritten and what couldn't.

Comment: Wrap your component in another component. Check out the decorator pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like this actually, but I think we can do something like that:

```
function Message2({ method2Function }) {
    return (
        <div onClick={method2Function}>Message 2</div>
    );
}

function method1() {
    console.log('Method 1');
}

function method2() {
    console.log('Method 2');
}

function SimpleComponent({ Message2Component = Message2, method1Function = method1, method2Function = method2 }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={method1Function}>Message 1</div>
            <Message2Component method2Function={method2Function} />
        </div>
    );
}

function EnhancedMessage2({ method2Function }) {
    return (
        <div onClick={method2Function}>Enhanced Message 2</div>
    );
}

function EnhancedComponent() {
    return (
        <SimpleComponent
            Message2Component={EnhancedMessage2}
            method1Function={() => { console.log('Enhanced Method 1'); }}
            method2Function={() => { console.log('Enhanced Method 2'); }}
        />
    );
}
```